# MDX query for hierarchical inclusion/exclusion

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I'm trying to craft an MDX query to answer a question of the form:

Show me all records in 2008, except those in November, unless they occurred on November 17th.

The query has to be generalized to working with more than just three clauses and should not be date specific.  (I'm asking using dates as an example because it's easy to understand - I'm interested in generalizing my MDX for different hierarchies.

This is the closest I've gotten so far:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY {     [Measures].[Session Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY {     ([SessionIDs].[Session ID].Children) } ON ROWS 
FROM (
      SELECT 
            Union(
                  Descendants([Start Date].[Date].Year.[2008], , LEAVES), 
                  Descendants([Start Date].[Date].[Date].&[20081117], , LEAVES)
            )
            -
            Descendants([Start Date].[Date].[Month].&[2008]&[11], , LEAVES)
             ON COLUMNS
      FROM [ADM]  
) ;
```

The problem is that the secondary inclusion (Nov 17, 2008) is eliminated by the exclusion.  I've tried maintaining duplicates in the first union, however Exclude (minus operator) eliminates all copies of members that match.

Edit:

Here is another example to help in understanding what I mean when I ask for a "generalizable" solution.

Consider a mapping application where a user can select to see data in geographical regions of their choice.  They choose these regions by zooming in and out of the map, and selecting/deselecting [quadkeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx).  Quadkeys map neatly to a hierarchy, which is typically somewhere between 18 and 23 levels deep.

A valid use case would then be:

- Select   QK0
- Deselect QK002
- Select   QK0021230
- Deselect QK002123033201 and QK002123033202

In words (and completely fabricating the place names that map to these quadkeys), this would be something like: Show me all of the data for North America but not data for USA unless that data is for New York State, but not in Albany or Glens Falls.

So the same query structure that worked for dates, above, must work for mapping or any other hierarchical set.  It is also worth noting that I'm constructing this MDX on the fly in response to user actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [subselect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487138.aspx) you just need to put this on the column:

```
{Except([Start Date].[Date].Month.Members, {[Start Date].[Date].[Month].&[2008]&[11]}), [Start Date].[Date].[Date].&[20081117]}
```

I assumed that you have a Month level. The first part of the expression will return all the monthes but November 2008, then November 17 2008 is added.

EDIT:

For your second example you can write something like this:

```
Except(all the cities in north america, 
        Except(all the cities in USA, 
                Except(all the cities in New York state,
                        {Albany , Glens Falls})))
```

You can retrieve the cities in the North America, in the USA and in New York state with the `Descendants` function and the `LEAVES` flag.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be generalizable though.  It works alright for the given example.  I'll post another example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you mean by "working with more than just three clauses... any hierarchy" but here is the set you're requesting :

```
select 

  Hierarchize (
    Union(
      Except(     
        Descendants( [Start Date].[Date].[Year].[2008]       , [Start Date].[Date].[Month], SELF ),
        Descendants( [Start Date].[Date].[Month].&[2008]&[11], [Start Date].[Date].[Month], SELF )    
      ),
      [Start Date].[Date].[Date].&[20081117]
    )
  )

  on 0 from [ADM]
```

Comment: I mean that I want a generalized solution that would work with any hierarchy and any number of inclusions/exclusions.  

Instead of the Date example, consider a mapping application that breaks the data down by quadkeys.  A user query could be: show me everything in QK0, except those in QK0012, unless it is in QK001200, but not QK001200132.  (etc.  A typical quadkey hierarchy is 20 levels deep).

What you have is extremely similar to what I came up with on my own last night.  I'm still mulling over whether or not it is as flexible as is required.

Comment: I added a large edit to the original question to flesh this idea out.